# Is better add a new method/action or add a new service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

Tech: Working with VS 2012 Web Api 2.1 C#

Situation:

I've a web api service with one method/action with very low workflow (only responses a 200 with a sample condition).
I've to make another method/action with a huge workflow (It has to connect to the database, consume a lot of memory, works with files, and so on).
Supose they work with the same entity, so they can be in the same controller.

**So my question is:** Is better make another service because the high volume of handling information? Or is the same, at memory level on the IIS, working with two methods on the same controller?

Which is the way that IIS work with this? Makes a copy of the dll service to every user?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE QUESTION: (Related)**

Supose the whole service has a very big size. Every instance has the same size, even when I work with a one-line method?

Comment: Your question is fairly confusing - I'd suggest to reword it and add more detail to it. What is "low workflow"? Do you mean load?

Comment: thanks, I've just update it!

Comment: If the two methods are going to have identical logic then that suggests to me there should only be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How IIS handles the web service depends on your configuration.

If you check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) : there is something called InstanceContextMode, take a look into it.
You can use this to specify if it makes a new instance of your service per call, per session or if it only has one which is used as a singleton.

I've never worked specifically with asp.net; however, I do work with WCF. I suspect there is an equivalent for it.

As for telling you if you make another service, I believe that is too localized to really answer in a meaningful way.

Comment: but everytime is about the whoooole service, not only the method? I mean, Supose the whole service has a very big size. Every instance has the same size, even when I work with a one-line method?

Comment: The default value is for InstanceContextMode is to re-create the entire service per session (The service being the service class) as seen here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks a lot Aelphaeis, is that all I was looking for